# open/ closed set

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

If $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and $E$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then $f^{-1}(E)$ is necessarily: 
(A) CLOSED
(B) OPEN
(C) NEITHER CLOSED NOR OPEN 
(D) OPEN AND CLOSED.

I know the basic definition of open and closed set!

We define that a set $X\subset\mathbb R$ is open if for every $x \in X$ there exists some interval $(x−\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon>0$ such that this interval is also fully contained in $X$.

A set $X$ is defined to be closed if and only if its complement $\mathbb R\setminus X$ is open. For example, $[0,1]$ is closed because $\mathbb R\setminus[0,1]=(−\infty,0)\cup(1,+\infty)$ is open.

now I was trying applying this definition to the given question but I got stuck!
$E$ being the domain of inverse of f is an open set therefore range will also be an open set, but I'm not sure whether this is the answer, also I don't know how to prove this.

I'm sorry I know I might be sounding silly to many out here but I.m not a student of mathematics but of economics, so all this is new for me!
please help

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: Check the definition of continuity... This follows directly from it.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer part (A) and part (B). (The answers imply (C) and (D). )

(A): Counter example:
Let $f: x \mapsto x$ and $E=(0,1)$. Then $f^{-1}(E)=E$ which is not closed.

(B):
Let $y \in E$. Since $E$ is open there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(y-\varepsilon, y+\varepsilon) \in E$ $(*)$.

If there is no $x \in E$ such that $f(x)=y$, then $f^{-1}(E)=\emptyset$ which is open and we are done.

In the other case, pick $x\in f^{-1}(E)$ and say $f(x)=y\in E$.
Since $f$ is continuous, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every $z \in (x-\delta, x+\delta)$ we have $|f(x)-f(z)|<\varepsilon.$ But this simply means that $ (x-\delta, x+\delta)\subset f^{-1} [(f(x)-\varepsilon, f(x)+\varepsilon)] $.
So by $(*)$, $(x-\delta, x+\delta) \subset f^{-1}(E)$, i.e. $x$ is an inner point of $f^{-1}(E)$. As $x\in f^{-1}(E)$ was arbitrary, it follows that $f^{-1}(E)$ is open.